# How to count sum of products

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a action , ViewModel that shows totaly of product grouped by ProductName. But this doesn't shows me how many in every department.

Let say I have 20 computers in It-department and 10 computers in adminstration department then my code shows my productname which is "Computers".
And Totaly withch is 30 but not How many in it-department and the same for administration.

And the same for Servers or other products.

So I'am trying to use this action to get number of products in every department. I know alrteady departemnt Id's and those department are not populate dynamicaly.

// This is in my HomeController and this is my action trying to get sum of every department

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStatusOfDepartments(int ProductId, int departmentId )
{
    var products = context.Inventory.Where(x => x.ProductId == ProductId && x.departmentId == departmentId).FirstOrDefault();
    if(products != null)
    {
        return Content(products.Status.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("No products");
    }
}
```

And I want to call "GetStatusOfDepartments" action In this ViewModel but this givs me null. Can you please help me what is wrong
to call action in this ViewModel?

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductsInventory.Models.StatusModel>
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            Produkt name

        </th>
        <th>
           It-Department

        </th>
        <th>
            Adminstration
        </th>

        <th>
            TotalProducts 

        </th>


    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
       </td>
        <td>
          // Here I want to call like this
           @Html.Action("GetStatusOfDepartments", "Home", new { ProductId = item.ProductId, departmentId = 1 })
        </td>

        <td>
          // The same Here I want to call like this
           @Html.Action("GetStatusOfDepartments", "Home", new { ProductId = item.ProductId, departmentId = 2 })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>


    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: I believe it would be best to update the ViewModel being sent to the View from the Controller to include the status already.  Sending the model to the view, then doing additional work seems unnecessary.  Supply the view with the complete model you want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that stand out with what you have done so far.

- It's very unusual to see an ActionResult returning Content().  That means a controller is providing a raw string to a view, which is not really the point of controllers.
- Currently the view has `@Html.Action()` requests embedded within a loop, which is a big indicator that the view is not being provided with an appropriate model.
- The question's title suggests it has more to do with a database query than MVC.
- At the moment, a single page load will result in many database queries, at least twice the number of product types.  It is best to perform as few database queries as possible as they often have a big impact on the time it takes to load each page.

In my attempt to answer this question it became obvious that there is a relatively complex database query required to create the model.  Maybe you have ended up using the approach above as a way to get past that, so I will try and answer this question without a complex database query while still adhering to the MVC design patterns (that should avoid the issues mentioned above)

**Create a model**

You already have a pretty good idea of what you want to display on the view.  It's different enough from the database models that we should create a new model.

```
public class ProductsInDepartments
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ITTotal { get; set; }
    public int AdminTotal { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

This is simply a property for each column in your view.  I think you only have two departments and their names aren't mapped in the database.  If that's not correct then I would suggest a different model and approach.

**Controller**

The controller needs to prepare a model.  In this case, we will get all of the data, then transform it to the model structure we need:

```
    public enum Departments  // Enumerating a database key like this can be helpful if the database itself doesn't describe the numbers in a lookup table or something
    {
        IT = 1,
        Admin = 2
    };

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Status()
    {
        var Inventory = context.Inventory.ToList(); // Get all records

        var ViewModel = new List<Models.ProductsInDepartments>();
        foreach (int ProductId in Inventory.Select(e => e.ProductId).Distinct().ToList())
        {
            ViewModel.Add(new Models.ProductsInDepartments()
            {
                ProductId = ProductId,
                ProductName = Inventory.First(e => e.ProductId == ProductId).ProductName,
                AdminTotal = Inventory.Count(e => e.ProductId == ProductId && e.DepartmentId == (int)Department.Admin),
                ITTotal = Inventory.Count(e => e.ProductId == ProductId && e.DepartmentId == (int)Department.IT),
                Status = Inventory.First(e => e.ProductId == ProductId).Status // I'm not sure what you are trying to do with Status, so you might need to change this
            });
        }
        return View(ViewModel);
    }
```

**View**

Now the view is very straightforward.

```
@model List<ProductsInventory.Models.ProductsInDepartments>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>IT Department</th>
        <th>Administration</th>
        <th>Total Products</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var Item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.ProductName</td>
            <td>@Model.ITTotal.ToString()</td>
            <td>@Model.AdminTotal.ToString()</td>
            @if (Model.Status == 0)
            {
                <td>No Products</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>@Model.Status</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Again, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with status but for string overrides you can do those in the view like this and it's perfectly fine.  The view should handle various aspects of presentation-layer concerns.

Answer (score 0):

In @Html.Action the first parameter should be action name and second parameter should be controller name. You need to change your code to match that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did actualy but the same problem.

Comment: You have to run Debug and se if you get ProductId. The best way is to GroupBy productId in you ViewModel StatusModel, action you are using to populate Productname and status.